# Intersection between all elements of same list where elements are set

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x, set

I have a list-

```
list_of_sets = [{0, 1, 2}, {0}]
```

I want to calculate the intersection between the elements of the list. I have thought about this solution:

```
a =  list_of_sets[0]

b =  list_of_sets[1]

c =  set.intersection(a,b)
```

This solution works as i know the number of the elements of the list. (So i can declare as many as variable i need like a,b etc.)

My problem is that i can't figure out a solution for the other case, where the number of the elements of the list is unknown.

**N.B:** the thought of **counting the number of elements of the list using loop and than creating variables according to the result** has already been checked. As i have to keep my code in a function (**where the argument is list_of_sets**), so i need a more **generalized solution that can be used for any numbered list.**

**Edit 1:**

**I need a solution for all the elements of the list. (not pairwise or for 3/4 elements)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanted the intersection between all elements of `all_sets`:

```
intersection = set.intersection(*all_sets)
```

`all_sets` is a list of sets. the `set` is the `set` type.

---

For pairwise calculations,

This calculates intersections of all unordered pairs of 2 sets from a list `all_sets`. Should you need for 3, then use `3` as the argument.

```
from itertools import combinations, starmap
all_intersections = starmap(set.intersection, combinations(all_sets, 2))
```

If you *did* need the sets a, b for calculations, then:

```
for a, b in combinations(all_sets, 2):
    # do whatever with a, b
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the intersection of all the set. Then:

```
list_of_sets[0].intersection(*list_of_sets[1:])
```

Should work.

Take the first set from the list and then intersect it with the rest (unpack the list with the `*`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` for this. If you're using Python 3 you will have to import it from `functools`. Here's a short demo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

n = 30
m = 5

#Find sets of numbers i: 1 <= i <= n that are coprime to each number j: 2 <= j <= m
list_of_sets = [set(i for i in range(1, n+1) if i % j) for j in range(2, m+1)]

print 'Sets in list_of_sets:'
for s in list_of_sets:
    print s
print

#Get intersection of all the sets
print 'Numbers less than or equal to %d that are coprime to it:' % n
print reduce(set.intersection, list_of_sets)
```

**output**

```
Sets in list_of_sets:
set([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29])
set([1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29])
set([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30])
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29])

Numbers less than or equal to 30 that are coprime to it:
set([1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29])
```

---

Actually, we don't even need `reduce()` for this, we can simply do

```
set.intersection(*list_of_sets)
```